# Magento Delete all Product Images

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images

I have a magento Installation which has had several image imports done by the client and its got wrong images in the wrong products, toasters with fridge freezers as the initial import had the wrong img names.  After a further import via CSV it seems to have appended the images rather than change them.

I need to delete all product images on the site, then re-do the **CORRECT** import so all the images are correct.

Is there a quick way to delete all images then do a fresh import via Dataflow Profiles and re-map the correct fields?

Any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Fastest way to remove image,then follow below steps:
 delete all records from

1. `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery`
2. `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value'`

table  because magento is save all product image data  at those table.

Then index from Index management from admin  for set image black.

Then remove image `from dir`  then goto Your magento dir at `media/catalog/product`  and from this folder delete all file.

### Another Process:

Andy Simpson,you need a script which `is delete all product` from your system which will `delete from DB and file system`.

**Step1:** Create `a php`  at `root direct of magento system` which include `Mage.php at first code`.

```
require_once "YOURMAGENTODIR/app/Mage.php";
umask(0);
```

**Step2:** set `current store is` admin and set Developer mode

```
Mage::app('admin');
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
```

**Step3:** Get `Product Collection` and create a loop for get one product by one by one

```
$productCollection=Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
```

**Step4:** fetch product image by one and remove image one using below code:

```
$remove=Mage::getModel('catalog/product_attribute_media_api')->remove($product->getId(),$eachImge['file']);
```

---

### FULL CODE:

```
<?php
require_once "YOURMAGENTODIR/app/Mage.php";
umask(0);
Mage::app('admin');
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);

$productCollection=Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
foreach($productCollection as $product){
echo $product->getId();
echo "<br/>";
         $MediaDir=Mage::getConfig()->getOptions()->getMediaDir();
        echo $MediaCatalogDir=$MediaDir .DS . 'catalog' . DS . 'product';
echo "<br/>";

$MediaGallery=Mage::getModel('catalog/product_attribute_media_api')->items($product->getId());
echo "<pre>";
print_r($MediaGallery);
echo "</pre>";

    foreach($MediaGallery as $eachImge){
        $MediaDir=Mage::getConfig()->getOptions()->getMediaDir();
        $MediaCatalogDir=$MediaDir .DS . 'catalog' . DS . 'product';
        $DirImagePath=str_replace("/",DS,$eachImge['file']);
        $DirImagePath=$DirImagePath;
        // remove file from Dir

        $io     = new Varien_Io_File();
         $io->rm($MediaCatalogDir.$DirImagePath);

        $remove=Mage::getModel('catalog/product_attribute_media_api')->remove($product->getId(),$eachImge['file']);
    }


}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, I have created the php file and called it delete-image.php, how do I execute the script, do I need to visit the page via browser?  I have also changed catalog/product_collection to catalog/product as this is where the images are, is that correct?  thanks for your help.

Comment: use php shell execution,it is better process.... else  hit your file from  page via browser

Comment: for me... it is deleting the first product's images only

Comment: @AmitBera, is it need to truncate this table as well? TRUNCATE TABLE catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_to_entity;

Answer (score 2):

The full mysql statement for Amit's answer is

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
TRUNCATE TABLE catalog_product_entity_media_gallery;
TRUNCATE TABLE catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a quick fix to this unless you can reimport all your products from a backup export with the correct image data.

You could use a PHP script to loop through all your products and remove the media. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5709496/magento-programmatically-remove-product-images for more info.

You can safely delete /media/catalog/product/ and restore if you have a working backup with the correct image files.

Answer (score 0):

I used to Kevando on magento 2.2.7 but when import images again will not exactly. So this is my answers it's be tested.

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
TRUNCATE TABLE catalog_product_entity_media_gallery;
TRUNCATE TABLE catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value;
TRUNCATE TABLE catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_to_entity;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks "Amit Bera", It's saved my day and working fine

Just I followed the below procedure to delete all product images.

Fastest way to remove image,then follow below steps: delete all records from

catalog_product_entity_media_gallery
catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value'
table because magento is save all product image data at those table.

Then index from Index management from admin for set image black.

Then remove image from dir then goto Your magento dir at media/catalog/product and from this folder delete all file.

Comment: Can you please explain why -1 for this.

Comment: It's not an answer