# How to delete all product in magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I have more then 5000+ product in my magento website. i will configure to my local system, then how to delete all product programaticall also how to delete product image also in media folder?

I am using magento 1.9 version

Comment: You can get help from here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11838596/how-to-remove-all-catalog-products-in-magento

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to delete all the products and remove the images (media gallery), Create a file DeleteProduct.php inside your magento root folder and write the below code in that file and then execute it with below URL http://www.yourdomain.com/DeleteProduct.php 
try the below code :

```
<?php
require_once('app/Mage.php'); 
umask(0);
Mage::app('admin'); 
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
           ->getCollection();
foreach($productCollection as $_product)
{
    $productID = $_product->getId();

    try {
        $mediaApi = Mage::getModel("catalog/product_attribute_media_api");
        $items = $mediaApi->items($productID);
        foreach($items as $item)
        {
            $mediaApi->remove($productID, $item['file']);   // this will remove images 
        }
        Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($productID)->delete(); // this will delete product
    } catch (Exception $exception){
        var_dump($exception);
        die('Exception Thrown');
    }
}
```

Comment: Where i will use this

Comment: you can create a php file in the root folder and directly run it from your domain.com/file.php

Comment: I would suggest to add `<?php
require_once "app/Mage.php";
umask(0);
Mage::app('admin');
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);` at the beginning of the file.

Comment: it throw some exception error : Cannot complete this operation from non-admin area

Comment: check the edited answer

Answer (score 8):

Reset all product tables. Beware, below script will delete ALL your product data so do it carefully.

## To delete products

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_bundle_option`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_bundle_option_value`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_bundle_selection`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_datetime`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_decimal`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_gallery`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_int`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_text`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_tier_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_varchar`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link_attribute`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link_attribute_decimal`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link_attribute_int`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link_attribute_varchar`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link_type`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option_title`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option_type_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option_type_title`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option_type_value`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_super_attribute`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_super_attribute_label`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_super_attribute_pricing`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_super_link`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_enabled_index`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_website`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `cataloginventory_stock`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `cataloginventory_stock_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `cataloginventory_stock_status`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link_type`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option_type_value`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_super_attribute`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `cataloginventory_stock`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_product`;
DELETE FROM catalog_product_flat_1;
DELETE FROM catalog_product_flat_10;
DELETE FROM catalog_product_flat_11;
DELETE FROM catalog_product_flat_12;
DELETE FROM catalog_product_flat_13;
DELETE FROM catalog_product_flat_14;
DELETE FROM catalog_product_flat_15;
DELETE FROM catalog_product_flat_16;
DELETE FROM catalog_product_flat_17;
DELETE FROM catalog_product_flat_18;
DELETE FROM catalog_product_flat_19;
DELETE FROM catalog_product_flat_2;
DELETE FROM catalog_product_flat_20;
DELETE FROM catalog_product_flat_21;
DELETE FROM catalog_product_flat_22;
DELETE FROM catalog_product_flat_23;
DELETE FROM catalog_product_flat_24;
DELETE FROM catalog_product_flat_25;
DELETE FROM catalog_product_flat_26;
DELETE FROM catalog_product_flat_27;
DELETE FROM catalog_product_flat_28;
DELETE FROM catalog_product_flat_29;
DELETE FROM catalog_product_flat_3;
DELETE FROM catalog_product_flat_30;
DELETE FROM catalog_product_flat_31;
DELETE FROM catalog_product_flat_32;
DELETE FROM catalog_product_flat_33;
DELETE FROM catalog_product_flat_34;
DELETE FROM catalog_product_flat_35;
DELETE FROM catalog_product_flat_36;
DELETE FROM catalog_product_flat_37;
DELETE FROM catalog_product_flat_4;
DELETE FROM catalog_product_flat_5;
DELETE FROM catalog_product_flat_6;
DELETE FROM catalog_product_flat_7;
DELETE FROM catalog_product_flat_8;
DELETE FROM catalog_product_flat_9;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;

insert  into `catalog_product_link_type`(`link_type_id`,`code`) values (1,'relation'),(2,'bundle'),(3,'super'),(4,'up_sell'),(5,'cross_sell');
insert  into `catalog_product_link_attribute`(`product_link_attribute_id`,`link_type_id`,`product_link_attribute_code`,`data_type`) values (1,2,'qty','decimal'),(2,1,'position','int'),(3,4,'position','int'),(4,5,'position','int'),(6,1,'qty','decimal'),(7,3,'position','int'),(8,3,'qty','decimal');
insert  into `cataloginventory_stock`(`stock_id`,`stock_name`) values (1,'Default');
```

## To delete images:

```
<?php
require_once "YOURMAGENTODIR/app/Mage.php";
umask(0);
Mage::app('admin');
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);

$productCollection=Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
foreach($productCollection as $product){
echo $product->getId();
echo "<br/>";
         $MediaDir=Mage::getConfig()->getOptions()->getMediaDir();
        echo $MediaCatalogDir=$MediaDir .DS . 'catalog' . DS . 'product';
echo "<br/>";

$MediaGallery=Mage::getModel('catalog/product_attribute_media_api')->items($product->getId());
echo "<pre>";
print_r($MediaGallery);
echo "</pre>";

    foreach($MediaGallery as $eachImge){
        $MediaDir=Mage::getConfig()->getOptions()->getMediaDir();
        $MediaCatalogDir=$MediaDir .DS . 'catalog' . DS . 'product';
        $DirImagePath=str_replace("/",DS,$eachImge['file']);
        $DirImagePath=$DirImagePath;

        $remove=Mage::getModel('catalog/product_attribute_media_api')->remove($product->getId(),$eachImge['file']);
    }


}
```

Ref: (Thanks to Amit)

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11838596/how-to-remove-all-catalog-products-in-magento
2. [Magento Delete all Product Images](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/53356/magento-delete-all-product-images)